# Constructor overloading in Typescript with Object.assign

Tags: typescript, oop

I see a lot of questions about constructor overload tricks for Typescript.

Is there actually any reason why not to use an empty constructor and then instantiate the class like this?

```js
const obj = Object.assign(new MyClass(), {a: 'check', b: 'mate'})
```

Comment: This forces the users of `MyClass` to know implementation of it very well. Which is not good at all.

Comment: @Eldar why? `MyClass` is class. We attach data that belongs to the class. Now the behaviour is encapsulated to that type class

Comment: In your single line code a user must know that he has to initialize at least 2 string properties with name `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

This violates the principle that an object is responsible for maintaining its own internal state, and it tightly couples code which creates `MyClass` objects to the class's representation of that state (in the form of which properties hold which data).

A common thing you might want to do in a constructor is validate the inputs; for example, if your rectangle's width or height are negative, throw an error. Your code doesn't allow for that, because the properties aren't assigned until after the constructor has already returned, so the constructor can't see them.

Another thing you might want to do is add some extra fields with precomputed values. For example, if a class represents a vector with `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates and you have a `length()` method which computes the length, you might want to refactor it so the constructor computes the length once, stores it in a `_length` property, and the `length()` method returns that property. Your code doesn't allow for that refactoring, since the constructor won't be able to see the `x`, `y` or `z` values.

Comment: isnt this what mixins are for? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

there is data and then there is compatible methods which can apply to that data. Validation for example, can be an example of a mixin that applies to this data.

That's the whole idea behind functional programming.

Comment: How would using a mix-in allow the constructor to validate the properties, or precompute anything using the properties, when the properties are not assigned until after the constructor returns?